# Booting Kernel failed:Invalid argument

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel

I am trying to boot ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop through usb drive.But while i am trying to boot(I tried "try ubuntu without installing ubuntu") it it shows me an error like:
Booting Kernel failed:Invalid argument.
I format my pendrive and uploaded iso image files so many times.But still it showing same as above.
(I created partion in my D drive)
Please anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
I checked the SHA256 of the downloaded iso file. the value is not the same as the original, although the file size is the same. So I downloaded the Ubuntu image file (*.iso) again. Then it is OK to install.